# Como utilizar correctamente Created en Vue?

Tags: php, javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Esto tratando de llamar a un servicio con GET en vue utilizando created pero no termino de completarlo. (Fijense mi coment dentro de la funcion que es lo que me faltaria)

tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
async loadGoogleTagManagerCode () {
       let response = await ApiService.get('/config/company/google_tag_manager_code', {
          // hacer cosas con la respuesta para setear en el textarea / input / lo que sea el codigo del tag manager 
       });
    }
  },
  created () {
     this.loadGoogleTagManagerCode()
  },
```

este es el controlador en php:

```
public function getCompanyConfiguration(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $key = $request->getGetParameter('key');
            $config = ConfigurationService::getInstance()->getCompanyConfiguration([$key]);
            $viewArray = $this->buildAjaxSuccessResponseData($config);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $viewArray = $this->buildAjaxErrorResponseFromException($e);
        }

        return new JsonView($viewArray);
    }
}
```

y los datos importantes:

Se agrega el servicio para obtener el código de google tag manager code. 
http://admin.localtasa.com/config/company/

{key}
para obtener la key de google tag manager code se debe llamar con un get al servicio http://admin.localtasa.com/config/company/google_tag_manager_code

Response:

{"success":true,"performance_stats":{"memory_usage":10.426784},"data":{"google_tag_manager_code":"GTM-442233"}}

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví con :

```
async loadGoogleTagManagerCode () {
      let response = await ApiService.get('/config/company/google_tag_manager_code', {
        google_tag_manager_code: this.googleTagManagerCode
      });
      if (!response.success) {
        this.messageManager.showErrorMessage(this.translateText(response.message))
      } else {
        helperModal.removeWindowContentLoading()
      }
      return response
    }
  },
  created () {
     this.loadGoogleTagManagerCode()
  },
```